# How to count rows on dynamically created rows with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, row, counter

I am trying to make a system where I can create new rows and delete them too, I would like to have a counter that counts the row number of each individual row.

Under "Num" I would like to have the row numbers displayed, but I can't figure out how to do so.

EDIT

- I found a jQuery snippet that seems to count my first row, but not the newly created ones.
- Updated Fiddle with jQuery snippet
- Updated JS code with snippet in the top

See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pr05dw6p/14/

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 large-offset-2 columns">
        <h2>This is the table</h2>
            <form method="post">
                <table id="myTable" class="hover large-12 columns">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Num.</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Height</th>
                      <th>Width</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="bannerTable">
                    <tr>
                      <td><p></p></td>                      
                      <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                      <td><input type="number" name="height"></td>
                      <td><input type="number" name="width"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
    </div>    
</div>         

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-2 columns">
        <button class="button expanded" onclick="newRow()">Add new row</button>
    </div>
    <div class=" large-4 columns">
        <button class="alert button expanded" onclick="deleteRow()">Delete latest row</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
//CREATE NEW BANNER - TABLE ROW COUNTER
$('#bannerTable tr').each(function(idx){
    $(this).children().first().html(idx + 1);
});


//CREATE NEW BANNER - CREATE ROW
function newRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("bannerTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);    
    var element1 = document.createElement('p');
        cell1.appendChild(element1); 

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement('input');
        element2.type="text", name="name";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);   

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement('input');
        element3.type="number", name="height";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);   

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement('input');
        element4.type="number", name="width";
        cell4.appendChild(element4);   
}

//CREATE NEW BANNER - DELETE ROW
function deleteRow(){
    var table = document.getElementById("bannerTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    if(rowCount>1){            
        table.deleteRow(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length(count) of table rows as stated in other answers by using

```
table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length
```

This will get the count, and you can put it into the html of your generated `p` tag by calling `element1.innerHTML = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length`

I would also suggest running your `newRow()` function on page initialization without a preset `tr`. The count of the rows will also help when you insert a row so that it always inserts a row AFTER the previously inserted row, keeps the `Num.` column nice and clean too.

Check out this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pr05dw6p/19/

Comment: Thank you! This is exacly what is was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To count the rows you can use:

```
var row_count = $('#bannerTable tr').length;
```

you can call it at the end of newRow() and deleteRow() an append the result e.g. to a div.

Comment: See the code and tags of the question. OP doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: I have updated the tags to incude JQuery, i forgot to put it ealier.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do following changes :

- Add 1 as default value in HTML in the P tag
- In Javascript code we need count TR of table and put its value in table.insertRow(row_count); after that we need to increment value and add it to new `<P>` tag.

  ```
                   <tbody id="bannerTable">
                      <tr>
                        <td><p>1</p></td>                      
                        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="height"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="width"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
  ```

Javascript Code

```
//CREATE NEW BANNER - CREATE ROW
function newRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("bannerTable");
    var row_count = document.getElementById("bannerTable").rows.length;    
    var row = table.insertRow(row_count);
    row_count = row_count+1;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);     
    var element1 = document.createElement('p');
            element1.innerHTML = row_count;
        cell1.appendChild(element1); 

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement('input');
        element2.type="text", name="name";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);   

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement('input');
        element3.type="number", name="height";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);   

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement('input');
        element4.type="number", name="width";
        cell4.appendChild(element4);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var row_count = $('#myTable tbody tr').length.length;
```

call this after the add and delete row function